# Unable to hide text underline in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I am trying to hide the underline of the entered text when using the TextFormField.
I have read all of the suggestions, but none of them eliminate the underline!

```
child: TextFormField(
  autocorrect: false, 
  inputFormatters: [ new FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9]"))],
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
     hintText: "i.e. noahsclearnews",
     hintStyle: TextStyle( color: Colors.grey, fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(40) ),
     border: InputBorder.none,
     focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
     enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
     errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
     disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
  )
)
```

Am I missing something?

[image: Sample screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a native underline when you are typing unknown words in your keyboard independently of the FormField, actually isn't a thing in your app but in the android keyboard.

But you can ignore those corrections setting the keyboardType as a TextInputType.visiblePassword.

```
TextFormField(
    autocorrect: false,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword, // Disabling word correction
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "i.e. noahsclearnews",
    )
)
```

Comment: setting keyboard: TextInputType.visiblePassword did not remove the underline on the text. Or are you saying that setting it to visible password just removes its desire to correct the text?

Comment: setting keyboard: TextInputType.visiblePassword did not remove the underline on the text. UNTIL I did a full restart of app, a hot reload was not sufficient for some reason. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a space would work , give a space while writing and ur underline will be removed

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in usernames.